# Google Play Console - Switching between Closed Tracks

Tags: android, testing, google-play, google-play-console

Is there any way for the testers to switch between the versions located in different closed tracks?

I have 2 closed tracks created in Google Play Console and from my understanding, Google Play has in mind 2 things: Build number & invitation.

The tester will be able to test only the app version with the higher build number and only if the tester were invited.

However, if the same tester is invited to 2 different closed tracks with the same build number, what's the way to switch between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't recommended practice. But for a user to receive an APK on a closed track they have to opt-in to the track, and they could opt-out at any time.

So in theory they could be invited to any track, and then opt-in and opt-out of the tracks as appropriate. However, the opt-in / opt-out logic isn't instantaneous, though it is pretty quick. A matter of minutes rather than hours I think.

If it was my company I think I'd just use two different test accounts, or switch to using some sort of server side controlled solution like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) rather than two different testing tracks.